# Where are OpenCV's Video Surveilance BlobTracker classes?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

This is an embarrassingly daft question but I cannot find a class. I'm working on a motion tracking application to count cars passing a building and note their colour. I'm using [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/), a .Net managed wrapper around [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).

In the EmguCV samples there is an application `Emgu.CV.Example\VideoSurveilance` which would be a great start for my application, but I would like to look at the underlying OpenCV classes to see what parameters they work with.

Here's a simple line from the EmguCV example code:

```
_tracker = new BlobTrackerAuto<Bgr>();
```

then later:

```
_tracker.Process(frame, forgroundMask);
foreach (MCvBlob blob in _tracker)
{
```

Tracing that code back into [the EmguCV source-code](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV/VideoSurveillance/BlobTrackerAuto.cs) we find the following code in the `Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance` namespace in the EmguCV core project:

```
public void Process(Image<TColor, Byte> currentFrame, Image<Gray, Byte> foregroundMask)
{
    CvInvoke.CvBlobTrackerAutoProcess(_ptr, currentFrame.Ptr, foregroundMask == null ? IntPtr.Zero : foregroundMask.Ptr);
}

[DllImport(CvInvoke.EXTERN_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention)]
internal extern static void CvBlobTrackerAutoProcess(IntPtr tracker, IntPtr pImg, IntPtr pMask);
```

So somewhere in [the OpenCV API reference](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/modules/refman.html) I should be able to find a method like `CvBlobTrackerAutoProcess`. But I cannot find anything to do with `BlobTrackerAuto` at all.

So this is a long-winded way of asking where in the OpenCV API hierarchy are the BlobTracker classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding code is @ https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/legacy/src/blobtrackingauto.cpp#L206. It doesn't seem to be searchable/listed in docs. I suggest you just download the code and see. There are a number of classes implemented which might not all be exposed by Emgu.

Answer (score 1):

CvBlobTrackerAuto is in the legacy module, but I can't see CvBlobTrackerAutoProcess.  This question is somewhat related: [Why is the CvBlobDetector in openCV in the legacy lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860369/why-is-the-cvblobdetector-in-opencv-in-the-legacy-lib)

Comment: Thanks B, that question is indeed relevant. They seem to have retired a class that did blob detection and tracking in favour of one that does the detection better but does not do the tracking. Very odd.